# Visual Studio angle bracket alt gr not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, layout, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using (Win 10) Czech Keyboard layout (CES/CS) and typicaly I was able to write angle bracket '>' with combination of right alt (<kbd>AltGR</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>) but now Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition seems to ignore this shortcut. With message 'No quick actions availible here'. Any idea how to force Alt Gr or map this symbol on layout?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>) is associated with `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.QuickActionsForPosition`.
**Remove it.**

(keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> corresponds to <kbd>AltGR</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: Works fine, so Alt + Gr == Ctrl + Alt ..?

Comment: Helped me a lot! Exactly the same problem, thanks both!

Answer (score 2):

sometimes it happens when you make an rdp connection. disconnect rdp, restart your ide and reconnect rdp.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar is happening in **Visual Studio 2022** with **spanish keyboard layout**.

In spanish keyboard, you can type `}` using both `Alt Gr + ç` or `Ctrl + Alt + ç`. In my case, I'm used to the second option.

Oddly, when typing `{}` with this second option, by default, instead of having the expected behavior:

[image: Expected behavior]

you get this one:

[image: Actual behavior]

You just need to Go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`, look for `Edit.Edit.IntelliCode.Preview` entry and click on `Remove` button to unassign the default keyboard shortcut from this action.

[image]

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the reason was for the behaviour to change but I certainly know what caused it.

I was using remote desktop and developing on the remote machine using Visual Studio 2019. The day before I had no issues. Today, before I started the remote desktop session, I actually changed my keyboard to a lenovo travel keyboard. As soon as I started the session I got the problem that I could not use the `Alt+Gr` Key to type Stuff like `{` and `[`

So the solution was pretty simple. I restarted the remote machine and attached my old keyboard (maybe it would even work with the other keyboard) and it simply worked again like it used to.

Hope this helps someone without having the need to change keyboard shortcuts or delete some of them.