# Write curly brackets in visual studio with ctrl+alt+´

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration, ide, shortcut

I recently started using Visual Studio 2022 (Community Edition) to learn c++ and I realized that other editors let me write curly brackets using the combination Ctrl+Alt+´ for `{` and ctrl+alt+ç for `}`. The only way it lets me type the curly brackets is with AltGr, but it's not the way I'm used to. In return, to write square brackets it leaves me with ctrl+alt+` and ctrl+alt++ respectively.

I have the keyboard layout in Spanish and the operating system too. In other IDEs I have not had this problem. Investigating I have seen that in Visual Studio there is a shortcuts section but no option is what I need. Is there any way I can do this or any way to create a custom shortcut?

Comment: Does removing the `Edit.Edit.IntelliCode.Preview` shortcut, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70274243/1458097), solve your problem? I consider it a design flaw of Visual Studio, because it violates the "[Why Ctrl+Alt shouldn’t be used as a shortcut modifier](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040329-00/?p=40003)" principle. There were bug reports like [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts-clashes-with-the/38472) and [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-type-close-brace/289516) as well.

Comment: Hi, @Woody, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Alt+´`(English keyboard ' or ") is not conflict with Visual Studio Command.

`{` should be able to be input. You can follow the [step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70274243/1458097) in the comment   to delete the conflicting command `Edit.Edit.IntelliCode.Preview`.

Since it is a design issue, please report on the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp) and post link here so that we can follow up.